# How to get Object/Element/Control under mouse pointer of a external application window using c#?

Tags: c#, winapi

Im trying to change control border color of a external application window when mouse is on that control using c# ,
I have created a widows form application and set up global mouse hook for mouse move and im able to get the handler of the external window using windows api `WindowFromPoint()` method,
But im unable to get the controller under mouse pointer,
Is there any other technique to get the control to change border color when it is under mouse cursor,

Basically I want is a visual acknowledgement for display what is selected control in external application , any ideas?

Comment: Create a transparent window and place it over the control.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanx , Can I create Transparent Panel or something using winapi , ?

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I  found a method called ControlPaint.DrawBorder(); in p/Invoke but it does not draw border of external applications , can I used it for external applications?

Comment: You need to create a transparent window and place it over the control. On that transparent window you can draw your border.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks I will try ,

Comment: This will fail to work for applications, that don't use native windows for their control implementations. This is the case for pretty much all browsers, as well as (most) Qt applications.

Answer (score -1):

I have used

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
```

to get Client Rectangle and color it up using

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(hWnd), R, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

Thanks @David Heffernan